# Is there any way to execute 'cls' from node.js?

Tags: node.js

Trying to clear the command prompt buffer on windows from node.js.

This is what i'm trying that's not working:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var child = exec('cls', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

It still accumulates a scroll bar, which displeases me. It doesn't appear that CLS is ever *really* executed. If I replace cls with ls, it'll show a list of files though.

Answer (score 4):

I use `process.stdout.write('\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f');` but not sure it is gonna help you. Let me know anyways.

Comment: I think that works on my OSX box but it doesn't clear the buffer on my windows machine. :(

Comment: The [NPM module `clear`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/clear) uses this. Both the module and your code works for me on windows (C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Forgot `console.clear();` the classical function for clearing console
Works in nodejs and browser